# select persons who like apple and banana both

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

How to select people like apple and banana both from the data below?

table: MyTable

```
persons |  fruit
-----------------------------
   P1       Apple
   P1       Banana
   P1       Mango
   P2       Banana
   P2       Apple
   P3       Mango   
   P3       Apple
```

i.e in this case, P1, P2 should be the result.

I tried with

```
select * from MyTable where fruit in("Apple","Banana");
```

This is also resulting P3 because P3 also have apple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `group by persons having count(*) = 2`

Comment: Its resulting P1,Apple

Comment: Note that while doing group by and selecting another column does not gurantee which value it will return, in your case it will return 2 person p1 and p2 but may be since you are selecting * it will end up showing apple in fruit column. If you want both to get display use `group_concat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.persons 
FROM MyTable a JOIN MyTable b on a.persons=b.persons 
WHERE a.fruit='Apple' and b.fruit='Banana'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT persons 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE fruit IN ('Apple', 'Banana')
GROUP BY persons
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) = 2;
```

Comment: Its resulting P1,Apple @Saharsh

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
SELECT distinct `t1`.`persons` FROM MyTable AS `t1`
INNER JOIN MyTable AS `t2` ON `t1`.`persons` = `t2`.`persons`
WHERE `t1`.`fruit` = 'Banana' AND `t2`.`fruit` = 'Apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable where fruit in("Apple") and persons in(select persons from MyTable where fruit in("Banana");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select persons from MyTable where fruit in("Apple","Banana");
```